# How to make greasemonkey open lots of links, in new tabs, one by one?

Tags: mouseevent, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

### There are some links which looks like above

```
> <td><a href="http://Lucifase.com/pages/2000.php?refid=2000"
> target="_blank">2000</a><br></td> <td><a
> href="http://Lucifase.com/pages/3000.php?refid=3000"
> target="_blank">3000</a><br></td> <td><a
> href="http://Lucifase.com/pages/4000.php?refid=4000"
> target="_blank">4000</a><br></td> <td><a
> href="http://Lucifase.com/pages/5000.php?refid=5000"
> target="_blank">5000</a><br></td> <td><a
> href="http://Lucifase.com/pages/6000.php?refid=6000"
> target="_blank">6000</a><br></td>
```

---

### And I stop in first step.I can't open each of them by script trigger. Here is which I have so far:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       false, false, false, false,
                       0, null);
 var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
             if(links.href.search('refid') >= 0)

    links.dispatchEvent(evt);
 }, 1000);
```

---

But it doesn't work,also don't know how to make them open in new tab one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean one by one?  It appears that "clicking" all of the links at once is okay?

With links, must of the time, just follow the `href` instead of trying to send a click event.  The following code should open just the tabs you want:

```
var linksToOpen = document.querySelectorAll ("td > a[href*='refid']");
for (var J = 0, numLinks = linksToOpen.length;  J < numLinks;  ++J) {
    window.open (linksToOpen[J].href, '_blank');
}
```

---

---

**Update for OP clarification:**
To open the links with a delay between each one is slightly more complicated.  Code like this will do it:

```
var linksToOpen = document.querySelectorAll ("td > a[href*='refid']");

//--- linksToOpen is a NodeList, we want an array of links...
var linksArray  = [];
for (var J = 0, numLinks = linksToOpen.length;  J < numLinks;  ++J) {
    linksArray.push (linksToOpen[J].href);
}

openLinksOnDelay (linksArray);

function openLinksOnDelay (linkArray) {
    //--- Pop the first link off the array...
    var linkToOpen  = linkArray.shift ();
    if (linkToOpen)
        window.open (linkToOpen, '_blank');

    //--- Open the next of the remaining links after a delay.
    if (linkArray.length) {
        setTimeout ( function() {
                openLinksOnDelay (linkArray);
            },
            1000    //--- 1 second.  Use 60000 for 1 minute.
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: oh,you are right!I don't speak clear,my mistake.I want the script to open one link then open next link,there is time break between links.I would like the break time can be set by myself, couple minutes I think.btw, thx for the help,this script work also!

Comment: Okay, see the updated answer for how to put a time delay between link openings.

Comment: OMG!It's working! You are genius!!! I take part of the original script ("td > a[href*='refid']") ,then it looks so great now ^^

Comment: You're welcome!  Sorry about the typo, but it's awesome that you figured it out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be mouse clicks or can it open the links with this:

```
for(i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
  if(document.links[i].target != "_blank"){
     window.open(
       document.links[i].href,
       '_blank'
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, seems like works, it can open with window.open. But there are lots of links with "_blank" target also, I don't want to open them. How can I filter them?