# Click many links, in one page, with a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I'm admin at 3 websites and my job is to delete unwanted items, usually clicking each item labeled "delete".  I want to automate the process. Tried to use some automation programs (Macro recorders) but they are static.

I'm not a Greasemonkey coder and appreciate if anybody can give me an idea on where to begin,

URL Pattern:

```
<a class="delete" href="http://www.domain.com/#!/item/delete/{id}">Delete</a>
```

I want to click the Delete link wherever there is a `class="delete"`.

**Each page contains 20 links.**

When Delete link is clicked, the page doesn't refresh, jQuery.

Comment: Reversed close vote.  This question would be closer to a duplicate of ["How to make Greasemonkey click lots of links one by one?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714395/331508), anyway -- but it's not quite the same.

Comment: Meta discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183196/i-got-a-question-closed-by-mistake-please-help-me-reopen-it-if-you-agree .

Comment: @BrockAdams I really did search for an answer before posting but didn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

```
var all = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
    var deleteUrl = all[i].href;
    var ifr = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    document.body.appendChild(ifr);
    ifr.src = deleteUrl;
}
```

You could run a simple script like the above in the browser's JavaScript console or make it a bookmarklet.

Comment: +1 for the iframe idea.  The code's a little brittle/dangerous though.  It should at least check that the node is a link.  Maybe use `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

See, also, ["How to make Greasemonkey click lots of links one by one?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714395/331508).

Since each "Delete" button opens a new page, a straight-forward click will navigate from the current page.  So, open the links in `<iframe>`s instead.

Use jQuery to make it all easier and more robust.  Here are **complete scripts**...

**For a simple, static page:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Fire lots of delete buttons
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var deleteLinks = $("a.delete");

deleteLinks.each ( function () {
    if (this.href) {
        $("body").append (
            '<iframe class="gmDelIfr" src="' + this.href + '"></iframe>'
        );
    }
} );

//-- Use whatever CSS you desire. Like `display: none;`, for example.
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    iframe.gmDelIfr {                           \
        width:                  80%;            \
        height:                 2em;            \
        margin:                 0;              \
        padding:                0;              \
    }                                           \
" );
```

---

---

**For an AJAX-driven page:** (Also works on a static page)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Fire lots of delete buttons
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("a.delete", clickDeleteLink);

function clickDeleteLink (jNode) {
    var thisHref    = jNode[0].href;
    if (thisHref) {
        $("body").append (
            '<iframe class="gmDelIfr" src="' + thisHref + '"></iframe>'
        );
    }
}

//-- Use whatever CSS you desire. Like `display: none;`, for example.
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    iframe.gmDelIfr {                           \
        width:                  80%;            \
        height:                 2em;            \
        margin:                 0;              \
        padding:                0;              \
    }                                           \
" );
```

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't seem to work, I have updated my question  (URL pattern) because each URL ends with a unique ID, when clicked the page doesn't refresh (actions gets submitted using Ajax). I've love to show you the page it self but it's within a protected admin area and can't be viewed publicly.  Greasemonkey seemed as a good idea for this, but if you can think of another method it would be appreciated.

Comment: State things like the AJAX behavior upfront, it makes all the difference in the world.  Now, a very important question.  When you click one link, how does the page change?  Post before and after HTML snippets. (And during HTML, if possible). This is because you will probably need to rate-limit the clicks.

Comment: After clicking the Delete label post gets deleted from database, and the label changes to Deleted without page refresh. After a manual page refresh the item disappears from the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "label"?  Not a `<label>` element?  Do you mean the text of the link? Edit your question to show the before and after HTML snippets.  Also, are all the "delete" links present on page load (with javascript turned off), or are they added by javascript too?